# PHP Mysqli get results if part of a full word is in database

Tags: php, mysqli

Say for example I want to search the word "TreeOfLight" in the database and find the row "LampOfLight".

Is there anyway I can get them to match by the word "Light" in both of them?

I have tried the following (note my variables are sanitized):

```
SELECT * FROM Presets WHERE areaname LIKE '%$mapQ%'
```

$mapQ being the input string.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Presets WHERE '$mapQ' LIKE CONCAT('%', %areaname%, '%')
```

However neither work for my exact use case. I need to match part of a word with part of a word in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL supports regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not very knowledged on regular expressions, could you lead me in the right direction?

Comment: @Difster `REGEXP` won't help for what the OP is trying to do here.

Comment: I think there would need to be some pretty serious AI involved to get that working.

Comment: Are your word strings always made up of capitalised words? i.e. `TreeOfLight`, not `treeoflight` or `TreeofLight` or `treeOFLight` etc.?

Comment: No, just in this example they were capitalised.

Comment: So how do you determine where the word boundaries are in `treeoflight`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Presets WHERE areaname LIKE '%$mapQ';
```

will match everything ending in 'light'.

```
SELECT * FROM Presets WHERE ( areaname LIKE 'e%$mapQ%' or areaname LIKE 'p%$mapQ%' );
```

will match 'eOfLight' and 'pOfLight' and any other e-something-light and p-something-light.

Answer (score 0):

I think these query will work for you
SELECT * FROM Presets WHERE areaname LIKE '$mapQ%'